# Web api response - unexplained total execution time

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I have Web Api method which logic executes under 900 ms (I'm measuring time when method starts and before response is sent back to client):

But total execution time is allways 1200 - 2000 ms...What could be 300 - 1000 ms which are added on total execution time from below image? How to debug this?

[image]

Comment: Well that's very little information to work with. Is there any additional detail?

Comment: Serialization/Deserialization and the actual transfer of data happen in those 300-1000ms. Your entire security layer (if you have security) also happen there.

Comment: Response is stream and no any security layer there...

Comment: First of all how you are able to get these times? Have you used `Glimpse` to check out the complete execution time and related stack?

Comment: Is this averaged over multiple calls? So ignoring the site doing any initial dll load/bootup ?

Comment: Yes, these are average results from 100 calls...